# How to apply disableGutters props on MTableToolbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm using react [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) and want to override default styles of toolbar to pass the prop disableGutters={true} as we can do in [material-ui toolbar](https://material-ui.com/api/toolbar/#component-name) .
Here is my  code

```
<MaterialTable
    // other props
components={{
          Toolbar: (props) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <MTableToolbar {...props} style={{paddingLeft:"0px"}}/>
              </div>
            );
          },
        }}
      />
```

But it's not working to remove gutter padding. I also tried `<MTableToolbar {...props} disableGutters={true}/>` but nothing works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MTableToolbar` has these classes `MuiToolbar-root MuiToolbar-regular MuiToolbar-gutters`. You can override these in this way by using `@material-ui/styles`. Install it first, `npm install @material-ui/style`. Then follow the code below:

```js
import React from 'react';

import MaterialTable, { MTableToolbar } from 'material-table';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  toolbarWrapper: {
    '& .MuiToolbar-gutters': {
      paddingLeft: 0,
      paddingRight: 0,
    }
  },
});

export default function App() {

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Toolbar Overriding Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
        { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
        {
          title: 'Birth Place',
          field: 'birthCity',
          lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
        },
      ]}
      data={[
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
      ]}
      components={{
        Toolbar: props => (
          <div className={classes.toolbarWrapper}><MTableToolbar {...props} /></div>
        ),
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

**Alternative Solution:**

There is another way you can use your own title rather than overriding the original one.

You have to copy props to hide the default title and show your own.

**Use `Grid` with the `MTableToolbar` so they still appear next to each other.**

Here is the code:

```js
import React from 'react';

import MaterialTable, { MTableToolbar } from 'material-table';

import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

export default function App() {

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Toolbar Overriding Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
        { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
        {
          title: 'Birth Place',
          field: 'birthCity',
          lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
        },
      ]}
      data={[
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
      ]}
      components={{
        Toolbar: props => {
          // This will let you use your own Title while keeping the search
          const propsCopy = { ...props };
          // Hide default title
          propsCopy.showTitle = false;
          return (
            <Grid container direction="row">
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <h2>Your Own Title</h2>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <MTableToolbar {...propsCopy} />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Wao, Thanks Buddy! You are a good Material-ui Developer! Salams from West Pakistan :)

Comment: @DevLoverUmar, My pleasure :)

Comment: Can you please answer this new question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64751661/how-to-add-a-scroll-bar-on-react-material-table

Comment: @DevLoverUmar, ok let me check.