# How to add a fancy scroll-bar on react material-table?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm using [react material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) and want a decent scroll-bar instead of default Pagination. I have tried [react-custom-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-custom-scroll) but it's not working as per my intention. The default scroll-bar of my App is activated. One more thing, how can I just apply this type of scroll on just the table body?

```
import CustomScroll from 'react-custom-scroll';
.
.
.

<div style={{height:"50vh"}}>
  <CustomScroll heightRelativeToParent="100%">

    <MaterialTable
    .
    .
    options={{
          search: true,
          paging: false,
          toolbarButtonAlignment: "left",
          searchAutoFocus: true,
        }}
    .
    />
  </CustomScroll>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using `CustomScroll`, you can do this by setting minimum(`minBodyHeight`) and maximum(`maxBodyHeight`) viewport height in the options like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

import MaterialTable, { MTableToolbar } from 'material-table';

import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

export default function App() {

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      options={{
        search: true,
        paging: false,
        toolbarButtonAlignment: "left",
        searchAutoFocus: true,
        minBodyHeight: "85vh",
        maxBodyHeight: "85vh"
      }}
      title="Toolbar Overriding Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
        { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
        { title: 'Birth City', field: 'birthCity', type: 'numeric' }
      ]}
      data={[
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
      ]}
      components={{
        Toolbar: props => {
          // This will let you use your own Title while keeping the search
          const propsCopy = { ...props };
          // Hide default title
          propsCopy.showTitle = false;
          return (
            <Grid container direction="row">
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <h2>Your Own Title</h2>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <MTableToolbar {...propsCopy} />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

**Update:**

Install [react-custom-scrollbars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-custom-scrollbars).

Save this code into the same directory as **`test.css`** file:

```css
.App {
    height: 800px;
}
```

Then follow the code below:

```js
import React from 'react';

import MaterialTable, { MTableToolbar } from 'material-table';

import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';

import './test.css';

const renderThumb = ({ style, ...props }) => {
  const thumbStyle = {
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(35, 49, 86, 0.8)'
  };
  return <div style={{ ...style, ...thumbStyle }} {...props} />;
};

const CustomScrollbars = props => (
  <Scrollbars
    renderThumbHorizontal={renderThumb}
    renderThumbVertical={renderThumb}
    {...props}
  />
);

export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <CustomScrollbars>

        <MaterialTable
          options={{
            search: true,
            paging: false,
            toolbarButtonAlignment: "left",
            searchAutoFocus: true,
          }}
          title="Toolbar Overriding Preview"
          columns={[
            { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
            { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
            { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
            { title: 'Birth City', field: 'birthCity', type: 'numeric' }
          ]}
          data={[
            { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
            { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
            { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
            { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
            { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
            { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
            { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
            { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
            { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
            { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
            { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
            { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
            { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
            { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
            { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
            { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
            { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
            { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
            { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
            { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
          ]}
          components={{
            Toolbar: props => {
              // This will let you use your own Title while keeping the search
              const propsCopy = { ...props };
              // Hide default title
              propsCopy.showTitle = false;
              return (
                <Grid container direction="row">
                  <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <h2>Your Own Title</h2>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <MTableToolbar {...propsCopy} />
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              );
            }
          }}
        />
      </CustomScrollbars>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Update 2**

This is another way you can add a scrollbar on the table body, for that you've to override the table body component, if you do that body will be messed up with the header. That's why you've to override the table header as well and do some styling. Here is the code:

```js
import React from 'react';

import MaterialTable, { MTableToolbar, MTableBody, MTableHeader } from 'material-table';

import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';

const renderThumb = ({ style, ...props }) => {
  const thumbStyle = {
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(35, 49, 86, 0.8)'
  };
  return <div style={{ ...style, ...thumbStyle }} {...props} />;
};

const CustomScrollbars = props => (
  <Scrollbars
    renderThumbHorizontal={renderThumb}
    renderThumbVertical={renderThumb}
    {...props}
  />
);

export default function App() {

  return (

    <MaterialTable

      options={{
        search: true,
        paging: false,
        toolbarButtonAlignment: "left",
        searchAutoFocus: true,
        cellStyle: { minWidth: '100px', maxWidth: '100px' },
      }}
      title="Toolbar Overriding Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
        { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
        { title: 'Birth City', field: 'birthCity', type: 'numeric' }
      ]}
      data={[
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
      ]}
      components={{
        Toolbar: props => {
          // This will let you use your own Title while keeping the search
          const propsCopy = { ...props };
          // Hide default title
          propsCopy.showTitle = false;
          return (
            <Grid container direction="row">
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <h2>Your Own Title</h2>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <MTableToolbar {...propsCopy} />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          );
        },
        Body: props => {

          return (
            <CustomScrollbars style={{ height: '650px' }}>
              <MTableBody {...props} />
            </CustomScrollbars>

          )
        },
        Header: props => (
          <div>
            <MTableHeader {...props} />
          </div>
        )
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks! That's very helpful,but what if I want to use a little fancy scroll-bar like slim-scroll or react-custom-scroll? default scroll is a little boring :)

Comment: Thanks Dear! It's working almost fine. Now, I'm trying to make it work on the table body with fixed table header. Not, found a way till now to override the default scroll component  of material-table with react-custom-scrollbars

Comment: Buddy! there are two possibilities! I'm either the most lazzy/dull minded developer or the material-table Docs are unclear! And probably the former state is true :p

Comment: Yes Buddy, sometimes docs don't clear the whole thing, :p

Comment: Here we go :p https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64784618/how-can-i-add-override-footer-component-in-react-material-table

Comment: @DevLoverUmar, let me have a look.