# How can I add/override Footer component in React material-table?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-table

I'm using react [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/). I'm having trouble in adding/overriding default footer component. By default, pagination component is rendered in footer. So, I tried overriding Pagination component to make it a simple footer like this

```
<MaterialTable
    // other props
    options={{           
            search: true,
            selection: true,
            sorting: true,
            actionsColumnIndex: -1,
            paging: false,   // true cause the rows truncation... i.e., paging anabled.
            showSelectAllCheckbox: true,
            toolbarButtonAlignment: "right",
            searchFieldAlignment: "right",
            searchAutoFocus: true,
            tableLayout:"auto",
            headerStyle: {              
              fontSize: "small"
            }
          }}
    components={{
            .
            .
            .
            .
            Pagination: props =>(
              <div>
                <h4>{"Total Users: " + users.length}</h4>                
              </div>
            )
            
          }}
/>
```

I don't want pagination at all as I'm using scrollbar as mentioned in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64751661/how-to-add-a-fancy-scroll-bar-on-react-material-table). So, in my case `options.paging:false` but I have to make it true to show up my overridden pagination/footer component. But making it true enable paging under the hood and rows after 6 are truncated.

I want to remove pagination and place a custom footer component. Let's say a span showing the total rows count at the table bottom.
`<span>{"Total Users: " + users.length}</span>`

**Material-table is Great! but I'm surprised why [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) don't have a footer component? If it's based on material-ui, it should have a footer component as [material-ui table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#api) have it.**

Comment: Why not use a separate component and attach it at the bottom of the table?

Comment: With a little styling it will look like a footer

Comment: Ok, if that can work, Please add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override pagination's icons and add your custom, you can install [@material-ui/icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons).

`npm i --save @material-ui/icons`.

Then you can override pagination without removing your scroll in this way:

```js
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

import MaterialTable, { MTableToolbar, MTableBody, MTableHeader } from 'material-table';

import { Grid, TablePagination } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';

import AddBox from '@material-ui/icons/AddBox';
import ArrowDownward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward';
import Check from '@material-ui/icons/Check';
import ChevronRight from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import Clear from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
import DeleteOutline from '@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline';
import Edit from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import FilterList from '@material-ui/icons/FilterList';
import Remove from '@material-ui/icons/Remove';
import SaveAlt from '@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt';
import Search from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import ViewColumn from '@material-ui/icons/ViewColumn';
import ArrowForward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForward';
import ArrowBack from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowBack';
import Bathtub from '@material-ui/icons/Bathtub';
import BatteryCharging20 from '@material-ui/icons/BatteryCharging20';

const tableIcons = {
  Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
  DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
  FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <BatteryCharging20 {...props} ref={ref} />),
  LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Bathtub {...props} ref={ref} />),
  NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowForward {...props} ref={ref} />),
  PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowBack {...props} ref={ref} />),
  ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
  SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />),
  ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />),
  ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />)
};

const renderThumb = ({ style, ...props }) => {
  const thumbStyle = {
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(35, 49, 86, 0.8)'
  };
  return <div style={{ ...style, ...thumbStyle }} {...props} />;
};

const CustomScrollbars = props => (
  <Scrollbars
    renderThumbHorizontal={renderThumb}
    renderThumbVertical={renderThumb}
    {...props}
  />
);

export default function App() {

  return (

    <MaterialTable

      options={{
        search: true,
        paging: false,
        toolbarButtonAlignment: "left",
        searchAutoFocus: true,
        cellStyle: { minWidth: '100px', maxWidth: '100px' },
      }}
      title="Toolbar Overriding Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
        { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
        { title: 'Birth City', field: 'birthCity', type: 'numeric' }
      ]}
      data={[
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
      ]}
      localization={{
        pagination: {
          labelDisplayedRows: '{from}-{to} of {count} rows',
          labelRowsSelect: 'Custom Label Rows Select',
          labelRowsPerPage: 'Custom Label Rows Per Page',
          firstAriaLabel: 'Custom First Page Label',
          firstTooltip: 'Custom First Page Tooltip',
          previousAriaLabel: 'Custom Previous Page Label',
          previousTooltip: 'Custom Previous Page Tooltip',
          nextAriaLabel: 'Custom Next Pabe',
          nextTooltip: 'Custom Next Page Tooltip',
          lastAriaLabel: 'Custom Last Page Label',
          lastTooltip: 'Custom Last Page Tooltip'
        },
      }}
      icons={tableIcons}
      components={{
        Toolbar: props => {
          // This will let you use your own Title while keeping the search
          const propsCopy = { ...props };
          // Hide default title
          propsCopy.showTitle = false;
          return (
            <Grid container direction="row">
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <h2>Your Own Title</h2>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <MTableToolbar {...propsCopy} />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          );
        },
        Body: props => {

          return (
            <div>
              <CustomScrollbars style={{ height: '250px' }}>
                <MTableBody {...props} />

              </CustomScrollbars>

              <h2 style={{
                textAlign: "center"
              }}>Custom Footer</h2>
            </div>

          )
        },
        Header: props => (
          <div>
            <MTableHeader {...props} />
          </div>
        ),
        // Pagination: props => (
        //   <TablePagination
        //     {...props}
        //     rowsPerPageOptions={[]}
        //     rowsPerPage={7}
        //   />
        // )
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dear, but I want to add a simple footer, remove the whole pagination component. If I can do that without even touching pagination, that would be great! I updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @DevLoverUmar, check the updated one. Remove pagination and you can do this on the `body` section as well.

Comment: @DevLoverUmar, ha ha ha. It's ok.